# bootstrap- how to align structure properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a page in my laravel that shows my list of category items like below:

What I am trying to do is to use bootstrap and split them into rows and column. Then the top part consist of category row where it displays 4 images instead of 3. And then in subsequent rows, it should display 4 items in each row where I highlighted it in blue. However I place the sidebar into the row as well with each object occupying 3 columns so the fourth image on the 1st row will be scaled down.

My code:

```css
.col-3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-2">
      <ul>
        Aside
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-3 text-center">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 text-center">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 text-center">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 text-center">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
```

How would I set the grid system so it aligns elegantly?

Comment: please create a working snippet out of your code, it misses some style

Comment: I clean up your code (Very hard for users to answer if you put mega-bulk of code - copy-paste + without indentation). I keep up only your original cols (Layout). For the future - it's very hard to debug layout like this. Roya answers your Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nested grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting) and create a row within your row.

```css
.col-md-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

.col-md-2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: and every subsequent row for items will be next to the sidebar and below the 1st row?

Comment: Yes, you can more add rows inside your col-md-10 class and below the nested row.